# Eloquent ORM - join by existing relation

Tags: mysql, join, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm working with Eloquent ORM 4 - without Laravel Framework.

As I noticed, this ORM is really close to Ruby's "Active Record".

In my situation I need to have a model with a lot of relationships. Also, I need to search this objects **with relations**. So, I have to use **joins**.

But it makes doubled code. **Example**:

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Color', 'products_colors', 'product_id', 'color_id');
}

public function scopeJoinColors()
{
    return $this->join('product_colors', 'products.id', '=', 'products_colors.product.id')
        ->join('colors', 'product_colors.color_id', '=', 'colors.id')
}
```

In this way there are a lot of same things.
And in the fact, I need to restrict relation and join in the same way like this:

```
...->where('products_colors.published', '=', 1)
```

So, **the question**
Is it possible in Eloquent make joins by existing relations?
If not, how do you manage with those tricky situations?

And **one more question**.
What do you do, if you need 2 or more joins to one table? I mean EAV.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the Eloquent way to have relationships only where a certain condition is met, but it can be done through the query builder, just pass the join function a closure.  This should answer both of your questions as well.

```
return $this->join('product_colors', 'products.id', '=', 'products_colors.product.id')
    ->join('colors', function($join)
       $join->on('colors.published','=','1');
       $join->on('colors.id', '=', 'products.color_id');
    });
```

Comment: the question was "Is it possible in Eloquent make joins by existing relations?"